# Subclassing `int` to make colors

Tags: python, object-oriented, immutability

In the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) framework (originally a C++ framework, but python bindings are also supplied), colors are objects ([`ROOT.TColor`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTColor.html)) identified with an integer index.

This short class creates a new such color, given the `r, g, b` values which stores the object inside an `int` sub-type (to prevent the gc from deleting it).

```
#colors.py
import ROOT


class Color(int):
    """Create a new ROOT.TColor object with an associated index"""
    __slots__ = ["object"]

    def __new__(cls, r, g, b):
        """Constructor. r, g, b are in [0, 1]"""
        self = int.__new__(cls, ROOT.TColor.GetFreeColorIndex())
        cls.set_rgb(self, r, g, b)
        return self

    def set_rgb(self, r, g, b):
        self.object = ROOT.TColor(self, r, g, b)


black = Color(0, 0, 0)
orange = Color(0.9, 0.6, 0)
sky_blue = Color(0.35, 0.7, 0.9)
bluish_green = Color(0, 0.6, 0.5)
yellow = Color(0.95, 0.9, 0.25)
blue = Color(0, 0.45, 0.7)
vermillion = Color(0.8, 0.4, 0)
reddish_purple = Color(0.8, 0.6, 0.7)

colors = [black, orange, sky_blue, bluish_green,
          yellow, blue, vermillion, reddish_purple]
```

Usage example:

```
#draw_histograms.py
from colors import colors
import ROOT

names = "hist 1", "hist 2", "hist 3"
histograms = []
for name, color in zip(names, colors):
    hist = ROOT.TH1D(name, name, 100, -50, 50)
    hist.FillRandom("gaus", 1000)
    hist.SetLineColor(color)
    histograms.append(hist)

histograms[1].Draw()
...
```

I'm looking for comments on the class itself as well as recommendations regarding making the initialization of all the colors easier.

*Further explanation:*

The need for this class arose, because ROOT cannot convert a `ROOT.TColor` object directly to an `int`. It needs the global color index in functions such as `hist.SetLineColor(1)`.

Otherwise it raises errors such as:

```
...
  File "test.py", line 43, in plot_2D_stacked
    h.SetLineColor(color)
TypeError: void TAttLine::SetLineColor(short lcolor) =>
    could not convert argument 1 (short int converion expects an integer object)
```

Comment: I find getting the Python documentation hard, from the [C++ docs](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTColor.html#a22e6d504b14a0ea9cce280f4dea567ad) it'd seem like you could change your code to `Color = ROOT.TColor`. But you've probably tried that... I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @JoeWallis Yes, the python documentation is basically non-existent. But the interface is the same as for C++. This was actually what I tried at first, but while this probably works in C++, in python it complains that it can't convert `ROOT.TColor` to `int`.

Comment: @Joe Wallis the documentation also says you have to define the color index where you want to have your color available. The function `GetFreeColorIndex()` just ensures that you don't overwrite an existing index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [@JoeWallis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145850/subclassing-int-to-make-colors#comment273997_145850) in the comments, you could use the ["fast" TColor constructor](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTColor.html#a22e6d504b14a0ea9cce280f4dea567ad). This let you simplify the color creation by not having to manually deal with the color number:

```
import ROOT


class Color(int):
    """Create a new ROOT.TColor object with an associated index"""
    __slots__ = ["object"]

    def __new__(cls, r, g, b, a=1.0):
        """Constructor. r, g, b and a are in [0, 1]"""
        # Explicitly use floats here to disambiguate
        # between the two TColor constructors
        color = ROOT.TColor(float(r), float(g), float(b), float(a))
        self = int.__new__(cls, color.GetNumber())
        self.object = color
        return self
```

Or you could use plain `ROOT.TColor` and use `color.GetNumber()` whenever you need an `int` instead of a `TColor`. An other, untested (and probably not working), would be to define an [`__int__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__):

```
class Color(ROOT.TColor):
    def __int__(self):
        return self.GetNumber()
```

If `SetLineColor` and others accept that, this would be the best alternative.

Depending on the need, it may also be a good idea to define properties to get/set color components, such as:

```
    @property
    def red(self):
        return self.GetRed()

    @red.setter
    def red(self, red_value):
        self.SetRGB(red_value, self.green, self.blue)
```

Change `self` to `self.object` if you use the `int` subclass.

Now, as regard to style, you define a bunch of constants whose names should be UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. And I would probably use `red`, `green`, `blue` and `alpha` instead of one letter variable names, even though in "color" context, these letters are pretty obvious.

Comment: I tried implementing a `__int__` method, that didn't work. The other two methods I will have to try. The first I'm not sure about, the second should definitely work but make the interface harder, because I have to call `GetNumber` every time.

Comment: @Graipher Thing is that you need to differentiate between `TColor(0, 0, 0, 0)` and `TColor(0, 0, 0, 0)` where the first one tries to build a color by providing a number and RGB components and the second tries to use the RGBA "fast" constructor. Adding explicit casts to `float` will turn those into `TColor(0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` and `TColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` which should be enough to disambiguate. Will edit that in.